# mybatis search data first return only 1 rows, and second return all rows

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I use springBoot + mybatis to search mysql data, I found that some search only return 1 row, but if I use the same condition search again, it returns all rows.
below is the main code:

```
public void doBusiness(WorkerEntity workerEntity) {
    
        Date accountTime = DateUtils.stringToDate(workerEntity.getAccountantTime(), DateStyle.YYYY_MM_DD);
        String tableSuffix = DateUtils.yyyyMM(accountTime);


        long minId = workerEntity.getStartId();
        long maxId = workerEntity.getEndId();
        int totalCount = 0;

        // define beginId and endId
        long beginId;
        long endId;
        for ( ; minId <= maxId; ) {
            beginId = minId;
            endId = Math.min(beginId + 599, maxId);
            minId = endId + 1;

            PaymentProceedsDto proceedsDto = new PaymentProceedsDto();
            proceedsDto.setAccountantTime(accountTime);
            // other condition
            ....
            proceedsDto.setStartBatchId(beginId);
            proceedsDto.setEndBatchId(endId);
            updatePaymentService.searchAndUpdate(proceedsDto, workerEntity, tableSuffix);
        }
        ...
    }
```

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void searchAndUpdate(PaymentProceedsDto proceedsDto, WorkerEntity workerEntity, String tableSuffix) {
        List<Long> proceedsIdList = paymentProceedsService.querySumProceedsUnAccountList(proceedsDto);
        log.info("fetch sum proceeds unAccount ids end first, batchId: {}, start: {}, end: {}, size: {}",
                workerEntity.getRequestBatchCode(), proceedsDto.getStartBatchId(), proceedsDto.getEndBatchId(),
                proceedsIdList.size());
        
        if (proceedsIdList.size() > 0 && proceedsIdList.size() < 10) {
            List<Long> proceedsIdList2 = paymentProceedsService.querySumProceedsUnAccountList(proceedsDto);
            log.info("fetch sum proceeds unAccount ids end second, batchId: {}, start: {}, end: {}, size: {}",
                    workerEntity.getRequestBatchCode(), proceedsDto.getStartBatchId(), proceedsDto.getEndBatchId(),
                    proceedsIdList2.size());
          
        }
      ...
    }
```

mapper:

```
<select id="querySumProceedsUnAccountList" resultType="java.lang.Long">
    select id
    from <include refid="table_name"/>
    where id between #{proceedsDto.startBatchId} and #{proceedsDto.endBatchId}
    and <include refid="querySumProceedsUnAccountCondition"/>
  </select>
  <sql id="querySumProceedsUnAccountCondition">
    accountant_time = #{proceedsDto.accountantTime}
    and enter_accounts_state = #{proceedsDto.enterAccountsState}
    and enter_ce_state = #{proceedsDto.enterCeState}
    and ebs_summary_state = #{proceedsDto.ebsSummaryState}
    and is_del = 0
  </sql>
```

if my loop batch size is 599, also like sql id between 1 and 599. it need return 600 size, but first search just return 1 row, and same condition second search return 600 rows.

and I also try set the batch size to 1000, first search also just return 1 row, and second search return 1001 rows.

here is first search log:

```
[xxx] [DEBUG] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.532] [o.a.i.l.j.BaseJdbcLogger:debug:137] [pool-6-thread-1] ==>  Preparing: select id from 
payment_proceeds_current where id between ? and ? and accountant_time = ? and enter_accounts_state = ? and enter_ce_state = ? and ebs_summary_state = ? and
 is_del = 0[TID:N/A]
[xxx] [DEBUG] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.532] [o.a.i.l.j.BaseJdbcLogger:debug:137] [pool-6-thread-1] ==> Parameters: 134744124(Long)
, 134744723(Long), 2021-05-31 00:00:00.0(Timestamp), 1(Integer), 2(Integer), 2(Integer)[TID:552267.108.16306558875320157]
[xxx] [DEBUG] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.534] [o.a.i.l.j.BaseJdbcLogger:debug:137] [pool-6-thread-1] <==      Total: 1[TID:552267.10
8.16306558875320157]
[xxx] [INFO ] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.535] [c.b.r.r.e.i.UpdatePaymentServiceImpl:searchAndUpdate:44] [pool-6-thread-1] fetch sum 
proceeds unAccount ids end first, batchId: 20210901225304381, start: 134744124, end: 134744723, size: 1[TID:N/A]
```

second search log:

```
[xxx] [DEBUG] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.535] [o.a.i.l.j.BaseJdbcLogger:debug:137] [pool-6-thread-1] ==>  Preparing: select id from 
payment_proceeds_current where id between ? and ? and accountant_time = ? and enter_accounts_state = ? and enter_ce_state = ? and ebs_summary_state = ? and
 is_del = 0[TID:N/A]
[xxx] [DEBUG] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.536] [o.a.i.l.j.BaseJdbcLogger:debug:137] [pool-6-thread-1] ==> Parameters: 134744124(Long)
, 134744723(Long), 2021-05-31 00:00:00.0(Timestamp), 1(Integer), 2(Integer), 2(Integer)[TID:552267.108.16306558875360159]
[xxx] [DEBUG] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.538] [o.a.i.l.j.BaseJdbcLogger:debug:137] [pool-6-thread-1] <==      Total: 600[TID:552267.
108.16306558875360159]
[xxx] [INFO ] [2021-09-03 15:58:07.539] [c.b.r.r.e.i.UpdatePaymentServiceImpl:searchAndUpdate:49] [pool-6-thread-1] fetch sum 
proceeds unAccount ids end second, batchId: 20210901225304381, start: 134744124, end: 134744723, size: 600[TID:N/A]
```

The mybatis local-cache-scope is statement and cache-enabled is false.

```
mybatis:
  mapper-locations:
    - classpath*:mapper/**/*Mapper.xml
  configuration:
    cache-enabled: false
    local-cache-scope: statement
```

I also try to upgrade mybatis version from 3.4.5 to 3.5.6, but it's not work.

is someone know how to resolve this problem, thanks.

Comment: MyBatis executes the query and maps the returned results. It does not control the number of rows returned from the query. If you could create and share a small project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) which reproduces the same problem, I would look into it.

Comment: thanks.My tasks ran in distributed with 24 machines, but I found that if it ran in only one thread， worked normal。I don't know if exist thread not safe, use springBoot & mybaits

Comment: Forget Spring Boot and MyBatis. It's the MySQL server that returns one row, so you should investigate why there is only one row in the DB matching the criteria. For example, it could make sense if the other rows are not committed by other threads when the SELECT is executed.

Comment: All of the data already exist in db before execute the task, and the db transaction_isolation and tx_isolation is READ-COMMITTED. I dont' know why it run normal in single thread, but also abnormal in distributed.

Comment: It's really hard to advice without seeing what exactly you are doing in those machines, but READ_COMMITTED might not be strict enough for your application as it does not avoid non-repeatable read or phantom read. If you haven't tried it, change the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE and see what happens.

Comment: It seems that really have relation with  mysql iso, when I add 'for update' for the select sql, it worked normal, but I can not understand why It return only first row of the batch. like I select id range 1 and 1000, it need return 1001 rows, but only return first 1 row.